# Normal Spaces in topology?

Tags: general-topology

If $\prod X_{\alpha}$ is normal then is $X_{\alpha}$ normal too? I would guess it's not? But I have no idea of how to prove it. Is there any proof to prove the claim or a counterexample otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

If $X=\prod_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha$ is normal, then each factor $X_\alpha$ must be normal as well. Fix $\alpha\in A$, and let $H$ and $K$ be disjoint closed subsets of $X_\alpha$. Then $\pi_\alpha^{-1}[H]$ and $\pi_\alpha^{-1}[K]$ are disjoint closed subsets of $X$, where $\pi_\alpha:X\to X_\alpha$ is the usual projection map. $X$ is normal, so there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ in $X$ such that $\pi_\alpha^{-1}[H]\subseteq H$ and $\pi_\alpha^{-1}[K]\subseteq V$. Let $x=\langle x_\beta:\beta\in A\rangle$ be any point of $X$, and let $$Y=\big\{\langle y_\beta:\beta\in A\rangle\in X:y_\beta=x_\beta\text{ for all }\beta\in A\setminus\{\alpha\}\big\}\;.$$

Let $h=\pi_\alpha\upharpoonright Y$, the restriction of the $\alpha$-th projection map to $Y$; then $h$ is a homeomorphism, and $h[U\cap Y]$ and $h[V\cap Y]$ are disjoint open subsets of $X_\alpha$ such that $H\subseteq h[U\cap Y]$ and $K\subseteq h[V\cap Y]$.

Comment: But I am trying to think about the other direction.. Would that be false as well. That is, if the product space is normal then does each space normal too?

Comment: @James: Sorry, I misread it. The answer is that they must be normal; I’ll fix my answer.

Comment: No problem Scott!

Comment: @James: It’s fixed now; I did leave a few things for you to check, but the key steps are there.

Comment: Thanks Brian! So, this gives us that each $X_{\alpha}$ will be normal and Hausdorff too for free right?

Comment: @James: Yes, if $X$ is Hausdorff, then so is each $X_\alpha$.